# need to get id of current element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have several tables that I iterate over using jQuery based on the class, but my behavior needs to change just slightly depending on the id of the element I'm in. Here's my code:

```
<table id="Brokers" class="nodeTable" border=1 />
<table id="Controllers" class="nodeTable" border=1 />
<table id="Cluster-Drivers"  class="nodeTable" border=1 />

jQuery(".nodeTable").html(nodeHealthTable({
  Role: jQuery(this).attr("id")
}))
```

this ends up populating Role with the empty string. How do I access the id of the current element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in your code doesn't refer to the selected element, `html` method accepts a function, within the context of this function `this` refers to the current element (jQuery uses `each` method internally).

```
jQuery(".nodeTable").html(function() {
    return nodeHealthTable({ Role: this.id });
})
```

Comment: @undefined didn't know that .html() accepted a function as well, I'll remove my answer because the .each() in my answer is overly complex then. Learned something new today :D thanks for that!